# Multiple SQL statements in one stored procedure. Out of Range exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using a data reader to get values from  a single table using 3 different queries. I get a "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" on "billed030", which is in the 2nd select statement below.

How can I query the database here, because the "where" is different for each query.

```sql
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT SUM(CAST(AmountBilled AS decimal(18, 2))) AS billed,
           SUM(CAST(AmountPaid AS decimal(18, 2))) AS paid
    FROM OrderBilling
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON OrderBilling.LinkId = Orders.LinkId
                               AND Orders.OwnerId = @OwnerId
    WHERE OrderBilling.PaidInFull = 'False'
      AND OrderBilling.OwnerID = @OwnerID
      AND ClientId = @ClientId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(CAST(AmountBilled AS decimal(18, 2))) AS billed030,
           SUM(CAST(AmountPaid AS decimal(18, 2))) AS paid030
    FROM OrderBilling
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON OrderBilling.LinkId = Orders.LinkId
                               AND Orders.OwnerId = @OwnerId
    WHERE OrderBilling.InvoiceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
      AND OrderBilling.PaidInFull = 'False'
      AND OrderBilling.OwnerID = @OwnerID
      AND ClientId = @ClientId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(CAST(AmountBilled AS decimal(18, 2))) AS billed3060,
           SUM(CAST(AmountPaid AS decimal(18, 2))) AS paid3060
    FROM OrderBilling
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON OrderBilling.LinkId = Orders.LinkId
                               AND Orders.OwnerId = @OwnerId
    WHERE OrderBilling.InvoiceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
      AND OrderBilling.PaidInFull = 'False'
      AND OrderBilling.OwnerID = @OwnerID
      AND ClientId = @ClientId;
END;
```

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 has been out of support for well over a year now; you should really already be looking at upgrade paths. As for the error, where is it coming from? That isn't a SQL Server error. Are you trying to reference a column `billed030` in your application layer? That column doesn't exist in the returned dataset if so; that query only returns 2 columns: `billed` and `paid`.

Comment: With `UNION (ALL)`, the column names for the result set are the column names from the first query.

Comment: I don't know why you have outofrange exception, but you can get rid of your billed030 as any alias in other than the FIRST query in union all does not make sense

Comment: Your current tsql will produce a resultset where it is IMPOSSIBLE for anyone (person or code) to distinguish which row belongs to which of your 3 groups. If that is something you need, then you must change the query to make that possible. Gordon has provided one approach.

Comment: I mistakenly tagged sql server 2008. This is sql server 2012. The error is in .NET 4.5, and was not getting values returned for billed030, paid030, billed3060, and paid 3060. If i delete the first statement, then "030" is first, then it works for that one. It just didn't work on the 2nd and 3rd statements. I tried with and without UNION All, and I just wanted to run the 3 statements on the same SP instead of coding 3 separate queries. I'm testing the answer below and so far it is working. This is very complex for my skill set so I'm thankful for your help. I'll report back the results.

Comment: I believe SMor is correct as it is impossible to distinguish which row belongs to which of the 3 groups. I have to Join Orders table because it has information critical as to who the the orderbilling table rows belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't specifically answer the question (which isn't a SQL Server error), however, I don't see any need for 3 `UNION ALL` queries here. You can use some conditional aggregation and then some unpivoting to receive the same data set:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SUM(CAST(O.AmountBilled AS decimal(18, 2))) AS billed, --If AmountBilled is in the table Orders, why a LEFT JOIN? If it isn't, why JOIN at all?
           SUM(CAST(O.AmountPaid AS decimal(18, 2))) AS paid,
           SUM(CASE WHEN OB.InvoiceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN CAST(O.AmountBilled AS decimal(18, 2)) END) AS billed030,
           SUM(CASE WHEN OB.InvoiceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN CAST(O.AmountPaid AS decimal(18, 2)) END) AS paid030,
           SUM(CASE WHEN OB.InvoiceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) THEN CAST(O.AmountBilled AS decimal(18, 2)) END) AS billed3060,
           SUM(CASE WHEN OB.InvoiceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) THEN CAST(O.AmountPaid AS decimal(18, 2)) END) AS paid3060
    FROM dbo.OrderBilling OB
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Orders O ON OB.LinkId = O.LinkId
                                     AND O.OwnerId = @OwnerId
    WHERE OB.PaidInFull = 'False'
      AND OB.OwnerID = @OwnerID
      AND OB.ClientId = @ClientId)
SELECT --V.category,
       V.billed,
       V.paid
FROM CTE C
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('',C.billed,C.paid),
                        ('030',C.billed030,C.paid3060),
                        ('3060',C.billed3060,C.paid3060))V(category,billed,paid);
```

Comment: This worked for me, except the "With CTE As( )" in the beginning and " Select v... From CTE C" at the end. I removed those and got the results I needed. Thank you.

Comment: That won't give the same results you define, but ok, @mlg74 .

Comment: It is giving me results I need. The added parts that I took out still give me the same out of range exception from the server, so I'm not sure why that is, but the Select Case part you gave work perfectly for me.